# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError , build process is broken

Tags: java, api, intellij-idea

I've a problem with my build and it caused a huge headache for me.

I had an old class and I was using it to fetch data from it, and I created a new class with the same methods. When I test it locally on my machine, everything works fine, but when I try to do a build, it broke because it's unstable and I got this error in the log file:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mashvisor.bean.Neighborhood.getTraditionalRates()Lcom/mashvisor/database/dao/views/NeighborhoodRentalRates;
at com.mashvisor.database.dao.PropertyDao.retrieve(PropertyDao.java:91)
```

The NeighborhoodRentalRates class is the old class, and in my code I'm sure im not using it nor trying to access it in that line, here's my code for that line:

```
Hibernate.initialize(property.getNeighborhood().getTraditionalRates());
```

and here's it's declaration

```
public TraditionalNeighborhoodRentalRates getTraditionalRates() {
    return traditionalRates;
}
```

The TraditionalNeighborhoodRentalRates is the new class, and the only change here is the class name.

Could any body help?

Comment: What build tool do you use? If you use maven, try to call `mvn clean` and then `mvn install`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is still calling the old method, i.e. it is looking for a method with the signature:

```
public NeighborhoodRentalRates getTraditionalRates() { ... }
```

Just using the same names it not enough. To have classes with the same (method-)interface, you have to have the same names, return types and argument types in all methods.

So you need to go through your calling code and make sure the new type is expected *everywhere* as return type and recompile the *calling* code.

Comment: Did it answer your question? If so, please accept the answer. Thank you.